# The code outputs only the 1st row

Tags: php, function, for-loop

I want to get employee name from `$projSDE_1` that consists of `emp ID` for each row in the for loop below from function `func_GetEmpName($empID)`.For the code below it should display 10 rows with `$projSDE_1's name`but the problem is the code outputs only the 1st row .Why the other 9 rows could not be display?Im already stuck with this problem for 1 week.If i remove the function it will display 10 rows
.All help appreciated.

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<db_rowcount();$i++){
  //loop through every result set
  $projID=db_get($i,0);
  $projNo=db_get($i,1);
  $projDesc=db_get($i,2);
  $projSDE_1=db_get($i,8);//1st Services Development Engineer

  $projSDE_1_name = func_GetEmpName($projSDE_1);//get name from function


}//endfor

  function func_GetEmpName($empID) {
  $sqlEmp="select EmpID,LastName2_c from empbasic WHERE EmpID= '".$empID."'";
  db_select($sqlEmp);
  $rowcount=db_rowcount();
  if(db_rowcount()>0){
    for($f=0;$f<count($empID);$f++){
      $empID=db_get($f,0);
      $empName=db_get($f,1);
    }
  }
  return $empName;
} // function
?>
```

[this the output from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OZM9.png)

[need to display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PZic.png)

[removed function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbbxs.png)

Comment: Please format the code part so it can be readable.

Comment: You are overwriting `$empName` in the for loop, so you are also returning only the last value after the loop. You need to put these values into an array, if you want to return all of them from that function.

Comment: how to store values from for loop into an array and return all of them from function.. need help doing that.

Comment: or should i use foreach loop instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033949/the-code-outputs-only-the-1st-value/52036558#comment91020052_52033949) said, you're overwritting `$empName` in each loop. Put the variable in an array to avoid that.

```
<?php

$projSDE_1_IDs = [];

for($i=0; $i<db_rowcount();$i++){
    //loop through every result set
    $projID=db_get($i,0);
    $projNo=db_get($i,1);    
    $projDesc=db_get($i,2);
    $projSDE_1=db_get($i,8);//1st Services Development Engineer

    array_push($projSDE_1_IDs, $projSDE_1) // Store all `$projSDE_1` in an array

}//endfor

$projSDE_1_names = func_GetEmpName($projSDE_1_IDs); // Pass the IDs' array to the function

function func_GetEmpName($empIDs) {

    $names = [];

    foreach($empIDs as $empId){

        $sqlEmp="select EmpID,LastName2_c from empbasic WHERE EmpID= '".$empID."'";

        db_select($sqlEmp);

        $rowcount=db_rowcount();

        if(db_rowcount()>0){

            for($f=0;$f<count($empID);$f++){
                $empID=db_get($f,0);
                $empName=db_get($f,1);

                array_push($names, $empName)
            }
        }

    }

    return $names;

} // function

var_dump($projSDE_1_names) // Display the array to see if you get all the correct data
```

Not very sure for the foreach part in the function but yb modifying little thing by your own if it's not working, you should be able to do what you want. I think the logic is here.

Comment: So far what i've understand,I can't simply output it using `$projSDE_1_name=func_GetEmpName($projSDE_1);`because the function will return an array. That means `$empNameArray` is an array.So,when i want receive the `$empNameArray` at view page i have to extract it using foreach..

Comment: thanks for help @Plum but its not working for some reason.
the for loop will retrieve more than one `$projSDE_1` as `$empID`.So the function could receive all `$projSDE_1`as parameter to get the employee name for each `$projSDE_1`?

Comment: @nhme Oh, sorry, I was focused on the function, I forgot the for-loop. Do you want to say that `$projSDE_1` is always an array or it's a simple value that changes every loop round ? Sorry, it's still hard for me to help without testing...

Comment: its value that changes every loop around

Comment: its possible to fetch one by one `$projSDE_1`  from for  loop  to pass into function?while the for loop is running,the function will retrieve name for each `$projSDE_1`..Some other said that the return in function that breaks the loop,therefore it will not read the other `$projSDE_1`.

Comment: @nhme I put all the IDs (I guess they are IDs) in an array and then call the function which returns an array with the employees names. I edited my answer if you want to try. I hope it fits your situation better.

Comment: thank you so much@Plum its work.the function able to output the each of the employees names. but, i need to ask,i need to pass the IDs' array to the function after close the for-loop?but i need to echo the `$projSDE_1_names`in the for loop so each row can have their own `$projSDE_1_names`..can you take a look < https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqjLR.png >

Comment: i add another for to display all the rersult.as the first for loop is to get the `projSDE_1` to pass into the the function `func_GetEmpName($empIDs)`..How to retrieve each `$projSDE_1_names `? I do this `$projSDE_1_names = func_GetEmpNameNew($projSDE_1_IDs,$projSDE_1);` and this the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/leaOe.png ..Thank you for your help and i appreciate so much.

Comment: if use `$projSDE_1_names = func_GetEmpNameNew($projSDE_1_IDs,$projSDE_1);
    foreach ($projSDE_1_names as $projSDE_1_name) {
       echo $projSDE_1_name.'-';`
 will show https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVTfh.png
All i need is one name for one row..tq